# Installing specific git releases via composer

Tags: 9, composer

I'm trying to install a specific release version of a library (pdf.js) into my D9 site, to which I've followed [this example](https://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/425/add-zip-package-drupal-using-composer-example-ckeditor-colorbutton-drupallibrary), and I have this in my composer file

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "mozilla/pdf.js",
            "version": "v2.14.305",
            "type": "drupal-library",
            "extra": {
                "installer-name": "pdf.js"
            },
            "dist": {
                "type": "zip",
                "url": "https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/releases/download/v2.14.305/pdfjs-2.14.305-dist.zip"
            }
        }
    }
...
...
"require": {
    "mozilla/pdf.js": "v2.14.305",
    ...
```

Except every time I run `composer install` it just gets the current master branch (eg, everything from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)), how do I make it get that specific zip I've specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out... this is fine, I'd been directly updating the `composer.json` file after my initial attempt to download it failed to get the correct version, and I was just being stupid by only running `composer install` and kept removing the folder manually each time it didn't download what I wanted.

I removed it from composer properly using `composer remove "mozilla/pdf.js"`, and re-ran the require line again, and this time it has worked.

I'll leave it up in case anyone wants to see how to download a specific version